# wkhtml blank page is added as last page

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I do have a problem with wkhtml and php. On every document I generate, I do have a blank page as last page. Here is my exec:

`exec('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --enable-javascript --margin-top 30mm --margin-bottom 25mm --margin-right 5mm --margin-left 10mm --orientation landscape --header-html "'.$env['HEADER'].'"  --header-spacing 10 --footer-line --footer-html "'.$env['FOOTER'].'" --footer-spacing 5 -s A4 --dpi 96  --encoding utf-8 --print-media-type --image-quality 100 --minimum-font-size 8 "'.$env['CONTENT'].'" - '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tempo/mypdf.pdf');`

The content itself is correct, but no matter how much or less content is on the last page, an additional page with no content is added. Is there something wrong with my executed script?

EDIT: What I've found out so far is, that this problem only appears when I add header and footer to my page.

Answer (score 1):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@Andi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3252019)'s question post.

> In the exec-script I have a "-" too much, right before the file definition. This is causing the extra page.

Comment: I was having the same issue with an extra page.  I had an extra dash "-" after the final switch. Removing the dash removed the extra page. thanks